# how to create a circle in android sdk

Tags: android

I am trying to build a workout timer app for android sdk.

I want to learn how to build a circle and how to slowly reduce it. Take a look a image below for example. I want to get the same effect but was ever able to get it.

Any idea how can I go about this?

[image: app]

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom view for this, it may be CircularProgressBar.
Please check #7 in this list [Android open source projects](https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version)

Comment: Keep in mind always that Link uses as a reference. So this must be a comment !!

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following libraries

- [CircularProgressDrawable](https://github.com/Sefford/CircularProgressDrawable)
- [CircularCounter](https://github.com/diogobernardino/CircularCounter)